# Typescript user input auto complete

Tags: typescript, autocomplete

I have some code I wish to make a user auto complete like thing.

```
var map = new Map<string, any>();
map.set("key1", 1);
map.get(/* Auto complete of all keys in this map. */)
```

So you put in a value in a string or something similar and it will make it it's own type.

```
type Keys = | "key1";
var map = new Map<Keys, any>();
```

Something like this but auto generated.

It doesn't have to add to a type, I did a little research and I *assume* that a `Record` would work? I am not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you seem to be asking for something like "incrementing" to a type in runtime. It is impossible.

```js
type Key = "k1";

const map = new Map<Key, any>();
map.set("k1", 0);

const add = (key: Key, v: any) => {
  Key = Key | key;
  map.set(key, v);
}
add("key2", 1);

// then typescript should suggest either k1 or key2 in the following line
map.get("
```

Which, ignoring all the compile errors, would be dynamically extending the type using a value. `key` there, which would extend `Key` type, will only be known in runtime. This can't work, the compiler does not know what is the value of `key` in order to suggest it to you.

You need to declare all possible elements of the type in compile time, so you would need to keep the possibilities hard-coded.

Comment: What about with express. When passing in parameter arguments, there is a property that you can access. `app.get('/:id', (req, res) => req.params.id);` What about something like that?

Comment: That is TypeScript's weird dependent typing!! You are correct that it narrows types based on a value. But it is based on a value that some function is taking, the value is narrowed in that context, and it goes away when we use a variable instead of a constant, for example use `let path = '/:id/;'` and you'll see autocomplete stop suggesting id, and allow anything like `req.params.asdf`. So, you still need the type to be hard coded to get autocomplete while programming.

Comment: How would I do something like that? It doesn't have to append to a type, I just need something like it.

Comment: it is impossible